# Sharepoint List auto ppulate

Tags: calculated-column

Team,

I have 2 Lists.

In first list i have 2 columns called ProjectID,project title
In second list i have same 2 columns

Requirement: When i select project title in second list,The projetc ID should auto populate based on Project title selection

Briefly, Once the Project Title is selected, the Project ID should auto-populate based on which project is selected.

Project iD is the primary key in first list and foreign key in second list

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like dynamically dependant drop downs (or cascading drop downs), are you doing this in an app or OTB. What version of SP? A little more info will help.

Comment: I am using SP 2010

Answer (score 1):

The version of sharepoint is important here. If you are using 2010 or 2013 you should set your project ID field in list 2 as a lookup to project ID of list 1. When doing This You can select what additional fields you would like to display. Choose project name here. This will not copy the data from one list to another but when viewing items you will see the related value.

If you want the value to be copied you will need to create a workflow to do this but there will then be no link between the data in he two lists. For example if the project name changes in list 1, list 2 will not reflect this change.

Sharwpoint is NOT a relational database so is very limiting in this regard...

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
Is there any way to acheive below command in the sharepoint designer workflow.
select projectid in pprojectlist where title="XX"

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you would do. You can look up data from a different list (must be in same site) where the value equals a value in the current item.

Comment: You will get a warning that your query may return more than one result but you should not worry about this if you have unique values

Comment: However, as stated above if the project name changes in one list the name will not be updated in the other list. But you could create workflow to keep the two in sync if required.

Comment: i am little bit confused..could you please explain more about how to look up?

Comment: yeah..i got now finally..

Project title(second list) looked up with project title(first list) and a ID column to show as additioanl field.

Thanks for helping me..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12995/discussion-between-samba-and-user23429)

Comment: Hi samba, I am sorry I am not available to chat now. If you need any more help post a comment and ill get back to you as soon as I can